# Facing problem in Subscribing Observable to component in Angular 8

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular8, angular-httpclient, angular-observable

I am trying to fetch data over httpclient , for that I used Observable , and tried to subscribe that Observable to the component 
Doing that I am getting error

> this.res.job.map is not a function
>       at SignupComponent.jobTitle

**SignupComponent.ts**:

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { SignupService } from '../service/signup/signup.service';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-signup',
      templateUrl: './signup.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./signup.component.scss']
    })
    export class SignupComponent  {


     constructor(private fb: FormBuilder ,public res : SignupService ) { 
   this.jobtitle() }


    jobtitle(){
        this.res.jobTitle.map((res : Response) => res.json()).subscribe(result => {
          console.log(result);
        })
      }

    }
```

**Service**

```
     import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { observable, Observable } from 'rxjs';
    import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';


    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class SignupService {

     constructor(public http: HttpClient) {}

  jobTitle() : Observable<any>{
     return this.http.get(this.jobTitle);
   }
    }
```

Comment: https://www.techiediaries.com/angular-by-example-httpclient-get/ You can Follow this tutorial

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We don't need to map it using HttpClient

Also you forgot to add paranthesis `()` to `jobTitle()` function
Try like this:

```
this.res.jobTitle().subscribe(result => {
  console.log(result);
})
```

Comment: I did same , but I am getting error =>>>> Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type '() => Observable<any>'.

Comment: Modified the answer, it will be `this.res.jobTitle()`

Answer (score 1):

Hi what the error is trying to tell oyu is, that `res.jobTitle` does not exist.
You are using it like a field of your Service `this.jobTitle` although there is none.
Therefor `undefined.map` is not a function.
In addition to that `map()` may only be called inside a `pipe()`

Also I am not sure why you are using the jobTitle as input to you `http.get()`.
Since `get()` wants an url as input and the rest of oyur code ready as if jobTitle should be your resulting value.

Answer (score 0):

For using RXJS operators(like map, filter, etc...), you need to use `pipe()` method for every operator and put all operators you would like to use inside `pipe()` method. So, operators are not methods as it was introduced in RXJS 5.5.

For example:

```
of(1,2,3).pipe(
  map(x => x + 1),
  filter(x => x > 2)
);
```

Old way looked like this (now it doesn't work):

```
of(1,2,3).map(x => x + 1).filter(x => x > 2);
```